# Primefaces LazyDataModel with unknown quantity of items throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading

I am trying to use a LazyDataModel to supply an unknown quantity of items to a `<p:dataScroller>`. I read them from storage as they are requested (from the user interaction) and then send the required amount back to the model.

The items do have an end, but I do not know the quantity until I read them all, so I set a ceiling of 1,000 items on the DataModel.

The implementation of load() in the Model:

```
@Override
public List<MyPojo> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters) {
    return managedBean.loadMoreItens(first, pageSize);
}
```

And `loadMoreItens(int, int)`:

```
List<MyPojo> loadMoreItens(int first, int pageSize) {

    int amountLoaded = 0;
    while(first+pageSize > this.list.size()) {
        if (this.endReached) {
            break;
        }
        amountLoaded++;
        list.add(readNewItem()); //readNewItem sets boolean if it reaches the end.
    }
    int end = first + pageSize;

    // do some other unrelated stuff like logging and such.

    return list.subList(first, Math.min(end, list.size()));
}
```

It is working fine, loading `chunkSize` itens every time user scrolls the component (so I will skip posting the JSF here), but when the end is reached, a nasty exception is getting thrown:

```
Jul 02, 2015 10:58:51 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(380) > toIndex(371)
```

the 380 / 371 figure here is test mass randomly generated, so the quantity may change. The problem is the end of the items to read is reached, but the model still thinks there are less than 1,000.

How can I avoid that exception from being thrown?

P.S.:

1. The items do not come from a database. There is no way to do a "light query" to know the quantity without acquiring all items.
2. The process of obtaining a new item is very costly (cannot tell what they are) and unless it is required, should not be done.
3. The managedBean is initialized with the first 20 items, that was in the requirements specs. There can be hundreds, or dozens. There is the hard 1,000 items ceiling.
4. The managed bean tries to get 20 itens before initializing the lazyModel, so I can set the amount right if there are less than 20 items, but it would be less than 0.1% of the cases.

Comment: You should count the items before, like a light count query, at least just for the first time if it's null...

Comment: @HatemAlimam It is not a database query - the quantity is really unknown until I read them all - and acquiring the items is rather costly, so the whole point is to only load them on demand. I initialize the managedBean with the first 20 items as per requirements specs.

Comment: The component relies on the count by design, your best bet is catching that exception somewhere...

Comment: @HatemAlimam the exception is being thrown after my code returns, by the facesEngine, and the only way I can think of catching it would be to set a filter and try-catch it on the chain.doFilter(). Setting a filter on the application would be outside the scope of the components I am designing.

Comment: See the github issue. There is a 'solution' there for the datatable and that can be ported to the datascroller I think. For a different workaround, see the old issue list in googlecode. Search for 'unknown count'

Comment: I will have to giveup on setting the count, and work around the framework. Since it is a `new-feature` on the PF project, lets wait. thanks @Kukeltje

Answer (score 1):

As @Kukeltje pointed, it is an issue that has been tagged as `new-feature` by the PF project leader, so there is no solution until Primefaces releases the feature.

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5750

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/51

The workarounds did not work for me, since the issue is for paginated datatables, and I am using a dataScroller.

The problem was with the subList() command; I had to constrain both indexes to `list.size()`:

```
List<MyPojo> loadMoreItens(int first, int pageSize) {

    int amountLoaded = 0;
    while(first+pageSize > this.list.size()) {
        if (this.endReached) {
            break;
        }
        amountLoaded++;
        list.add(readNewItem()); //readNewItem sets boolean if it reaches the end.
    }
    int end = first + pageSize;

    // do some other unrelated stuff like logging and such.

    return list.subList(Math.min(first,list.size()), Math.min(end, list.size()));
}
```

It skips the rest and avoids the exception, but the load control does not vanish from the page.

I then added a javascript code to hide it when the end is reached via remoteCommand.